# ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/mypath] due to exception [java.lang.NullPointerException]

Tags: maven, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, pom.xml

I am developing a SpringBoot REST API application built by maven, which I could run last week, but now something is wrong with it.

I can build the application without issue, and start it also. But when I call an endpoint, I always get a nullpointer which points to some inner classes of glassfish and apache.

This is the error I get:

```
Refunding-Auth: 2018-06-11 13:52:46,391 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.s.ErrorPageFilter:176 - Forwarding to error page from request [/mypath] due to exception [java.lang.NullPointerException]
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) [log4j-web-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.mapTypeAnnotations(TypeAnnotationParser.java:356) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl.<init>(AnnotatedTypeFactory.java:139) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory.buildAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeFactory.java:65) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.buildAnnotatedType(TypeAnnotationParser.java:79) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotatedType(Field.java:1170) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.TypeAnnotationAwareMetaDataProvider.findTypeAnnotationConstraintsForMember(TypeAnnotationAwareMetaDataProvider.java:65) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findPropertyMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:244) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getFieldMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:227) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.retrieveBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:137) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:125) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getBeanConfigurationForHierarchy(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:108) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.createBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:203) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getOrCreateBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:231) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:178) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.buildNewLocalExecutionContext(ValidatorImpl.java:775) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:758) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:684) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:419) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:761) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:684) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:1125) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.DefaultConfiguredValidator.onValidate(DefaultConfiguredValidator.java:175) ~[jersey-bean-validation-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ValidationInterceptorExecutor.java:113) ~[jersey-bean-validation-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.DefaultConfiguredValidator.validateResourceAndInputParams(DefaultConfiguredValidator.java:146) ~[jersey-bean-validation-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:134) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:?]
    ... 52 more
```

And I have no idea where and how to start to find the problem. I made some changes, but I haven't add any new dependency to my pom, this is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>myapp-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.my.app</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <swagger_host>localhost:8080</swagger_host>
        <swagger_protocol>http</swagger_protocol>
        <swagger_base-path>/myapp/api/v3</swagger_base-path>
        <sonar.tests>src/test/groovy</sonar.tests>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>myapp-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j Start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dblock.log4jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jna-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j End -->

        <!-- Spock Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- enables mocking of classes (in addition to interfaces) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib.nodep.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- enables mocking of classes without default constructor (together with
            CGLIB) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            <version>${org.objenesis.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder</groupId>
            <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.modules.http-builder.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spock End -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-api-doc</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/apidoc</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/automation/myapp/templates
                                    </directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>myapp.yaml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <delimiters>
                                <delimiter>@@</delimiter>
                            </delimiters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-api-doc-test</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/automation/myapp/templates
                                    </directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>myapp.yaml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <delimiters>
                                <delimiter>@@</delimiter>
                            </delimiters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/classes/application.yml,
                        WEB-INF/classes/application-local.yml
                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*EndPointTest*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*EndPointTest.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.codehaus.gmavenplus
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            gmavenplus-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.5,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Did anyone have the same issue? I would be really happy if I could find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was that previously I used @NotBlank validation annotation from hibernate.validator package, and then I changed it to javax.validator package, and that caused the problem. So I needed to change back from `import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;` to `import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;` everywhere I used this validation.